# ParameterizedRowMapper in spring-jdbc-4.2.4 jar

Tags: spring, jar, spring-jdbc

I am migrating my code from spring-3.1.0 to spring-4.2.4, but while using spring-jdbc-4.2.4 I am unable to found ParameterizedRowMapper Interface.
Can you please help to let me know, which interface replaced ParameterizedRowMapper in jdbc-4.2.4 jar ?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

As the documentation say's you should use `SingleColumnRowMapper` or the RowMapper directly:

> Deprecated.   along with SimpleJdbcTemplate, in favor of the regular
>   SingleColumnRowMapper
>
> @Deprecated public interface ParameterizedRowMapper extends
>   RowMapper
>
> Extension of the RowMapper interface, adding type parameterization. As
>   of Spring 3.0, this is equivalent to using the RowMapper interface
>   directly.

For more Information see the [javadoc of ParameterizedRowMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/ParameterizedRowMapper.html).

Comment: Thanks for the above answer. I have changed ParameterizedRowMapper to RowMapper interface, but it starts failing for various methods. like getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query()
getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt()
getJdbcTemplate().queryForLong()

can you please help how can I get rid off these errors ?
Thanks

Comment: Replacing ParameterizedRowMapper with RowMapper, it leads to many other classes and methods missing. Is this right approach or do I need to change anything else? Also if someone can provide any link which contains all the deprecated interfaces/classes and methods from 3.1.0 jdbc jar and their replacement in 4.2.4. it will be great help. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Replace this *org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.ParameterizedRowMapper*

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.ParameterizedRowMapper;

public class RootTypeMapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        RootType rootType = new RootType();
        rootType.setCode(rs.getString("Code"));
        rootType.setDescription(rs.getString("Description"));
        return rootType;
    }
}
```

with this *org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper*

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper; 

public class RootTypeMapper implements RowMapper<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        RootType rootType = new RootType();
        rootType.setCode(rs.getString("Code"));
        rootType.setDescription(rs.getString("Description"));
        return rootType;
    }

}
```